# Unable to push Avro data to HDFS using Confluent Platform

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a system pushing Avro data in to multiple Kafka topics.
I want to push that data to HDFS. I came across confluent but am not sure how can I send data to HDFS without starting `kafka-avro-console-producer`.

Steps I performed:

1. I have my own Kafka and ZooKeeper running so i just started schema registry of confluent.
2. I started `kafka-connect-hdfs` after changing topic name.
   This step is also successful. It's able to connect to HDFS.

After this I started pushing data to Kafka but the messages were not being pushed to HDFS.

Please help. I'm new to Confluent.

Comment: Which version of Confluent are you using? The latest one, i.e. version 3.1.1?

Comment: confluent-3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using the kafka-avro-console-producer and use your own producer to send messages to the topics, but we strongly encourage you to use the Confluent Schema Registry (https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry) to manage your schemas and use the Avro serializer that is bundled with the Schema Registry to keep your Avro data consistent. There's a nice writeup on the rationale for why this is a good idea to do [here](http://docs.confluent.io/current/avro.html).

If you are able to send messages that were produced with the kafka-avro-console-producer to HDFS, then your problem is likely in the kafka-connect-hdfs connector not being able to deserialize the data. I assume you are going through the [quickstart guide](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html#quickstart). The best results will come from you using the same serializer on both sides (in and out of Kafka) if you are intending to write Avro to HDFS. How this process works is described [in this documentation](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/concepts.html#connect-converters).

Comment: Steps I followed and faced the below exception.1)started kafka-avro-console-producer with own schema.2)started kafka-connect-hdfs.ERROR Task hdfs-sink-0 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data to Avro:atio.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:109)Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!

Comment: Are you using the same schema registry instance for the console producer and the connect worker? By default these are both looking for local host and to be able to lookup the schema you'll need to be pointing each to the same instance